# Convert a pandas column of 2D numpy arrays to a 3D numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe which has a row containing x numpy arrays of shape (y, z). I want to read it as a numpy array of shape (x, y, z).

`df.col.values` doesn't work, as it returns an array of 2D arrays, evident from the fact that `df.col.values.shape` evaluates to `(x,)`

In fact, `np.array(df.col).shape`, `df.col.shape` also evaluate to `(x,)`.
The only way I have been able to get this to work is
`np.array([a for a in df.col])`
but this seems more of a hack.

What is the correct way?

Additional Info: I need this because `keras.model.fit` wants the input shape to be (x, y, z), and doesn't like it any other way.

Comment: How about using `np.stack`?

Comment: @PaulPanzer That worked too.